# How to use a CancellationToken with the Azure Service Bus Queue client?

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azureservicebus, cancellation-token

In the Azure Service Bus queue client, I use the [`ReceiveBatchAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn130400.aspx) method to wait for a specified time to receive a batch of messages asynchronously.

```
var messages = await queueClient.ReceiveBatchAsync(10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

I'd like a clean shutdown of my application, so I'm implementing `CancellationToken` on all of my long-running async processes, but there doesn't appear to be an overload of `ReceiveBatchAsync` that is cancelable.

In other words, I'd like to do this, but I can't:

```
var messages = await queueClient.ReceiveBatchAsync(10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                                                       cancellationToken);
```

What would be the best way to apply a `CancellationToken` to a task like this that doesn't offer it directly?  I don't want to wait the entire 30 seconds during shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably could use [`QueueClient.Abort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagecliententity.abort.aspx) like this:

```
using (cancellationToken.Register(() => queueClient.Abort())
{
    var messages = await queueClient.ReceiveBatchAsync(
        10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    return messages; // or process it 
}
```

Comment: Looks good on the surface.  But do you know if it will actually interrupt the timeout?  I'll have to try it and see.

Comment: @MattJohnson, I don't know for sure as I haven't happened to use `ReceiveBatchAsync` yet.

Comment: If it doesn't, you can always combine your `cancellationToken` with a timeout `CancellationToken` via `CancellationTokenSource` instead of using a timeout in the call to `QueueClient.ReceiveBytesAsync`.

Comment: I ran into this today. This solution worked for me, at least in a quick check via Linqpad. OperationCanceledException was thrown when the token was cancelled.